# Parsing command line arguments in Haskell using getOpt

Tags: getopt, haskell

I am trying to teach myself Haskell. As a sample program, I am writing a Spider solitaire player.

I am trying to write a command line parser using `System.Console.GetOpt`. I know there are easier ways to do argument parsing for this program, but I want to learn how to use the `GetOpt` module because I anticipate needing its sophistication later in other programs that I will be writing.

I am trying to add a "--help" option that just prints a usage message and then exits. I would also like to print usage messages if either of the arguments to the "--games" option or the "--suits" option are not valid integers (games >= 1 and <= 1000, suits == 1, 2, or 4). I will be passing the resulting `Options` data type to other parts of my program.

I am also getting an error that `progName` is not in scope. Isn't the `case` statement in `parseArgs` in the scope of the `do` block?

Here is my code, patched together from the examples in ["Real World Haskell"](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/) and the [Haskell wiki](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/System-Console-GetOpt.html#g:3):

```
module Main (main) where

import System.Console.GetOpt
import System.Environment(getArgs, getProgName)

data Options = Options {
    optGames :: Int
  , optSuits :: Int
  , optVerbose :: Bool
  } deriving Show

defaultOptions = Options {
    optGames  = 1
  , optSuits = 4
  , optVerbose = False
  }

options :: [OptDescr (Options -> Options)]
options =
  [ Option ['g'] ["games"]
      (ReqArg (\g opts -> opts { optGames = (read g) }) "GAMES")
      "number of games"
  , Option ['s'] ["suits"]
      (ReqArg (\s opts -> opts { optSuits = (read s) }) "SUITS")
      "number of suits"
  , Option ['v'] ["verbose"]
      (NoArg (\opts -> opts { optVerbose = True }))
      "verbose output"
  ]

parseArgs :: IO Options
parseArgs = do
  argv <- getArgs
  progName <- getProgName
  case getOpt RequireOrder options argv of
    (opts, [], []) -> return (foldl (flip id) defaultOptions opts)
    (_, _, errs) -> ioError (userError (concat errs ++ helpMessage))
  where
    header = "Usage: " ++ progName ++ " [OPTION...]"
    helpMessage = usageInfo header options

main :: IO ()
main = do
  options <- parseArgs
  putStrLn $ show options
```

Comment: The scope thing is because the `where` clause is attached to `parseArgs`, where `progName` is not in scope (it's bound in the do-block). If you indent the `where` a bit more, it becomes attached to the `case`, and there `progName` is in scope.

Comment: (If there's a question other than "why do I get this error", you should state that question explicitly.)

Comment: Thanks. I indented the `where`clause until it was one indentation level more than the second case (`(_, _, errs)`) and it worked, but then I assume that the values `header` and `helpMessage` will not be in scope for the first case clause. I moved them up to be `let` values of the `do` block instead, and removed the `where`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the solution that I came up with:

```
module Main (main) where

import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Error
import System.Console.GetOpt
import System.Environment(getArgs, getProgName)

data Options = Options {
    optGames :: Int
  , optSuits :: Int
  , optVerbose :: Bool
  } deriving Show

defaultOptions = Options {
    optGames  = 1
  , optSuits = 4
  , optVerbose = False
  }

options :: [OptDescr (Options -> Either String Options)]
options =
  [ Option ['g'] ["games"]
      (ReqArg (\g opts ->
        case reads g of
          [(games, "")] | games >= 1 && games <= 1000 -> Right opts { optGames = games }
          _ -> Left "--games must be a number between 1 and 1000"
        ) "GAMES")
      "number of games"
  , Option ['s'] ["suits"]
      (ReqArg (\s opts ->
        case reads s of
          [(suits, "")] | suits `elem` [1, 2, 4] -> Right opts { optSuits = suits }
          _ -> Left "--suits must be 1, 2, or 4"
        ) "SUITS")
      "number of suits"
  , Option ['v'] ["verbose"]
      (NoArg (\opts -> Right opts { optVerbose = True }))
      "verbose output"
  ]

parseArgs :: IO Options
parseArgs = do
  argv <- getArgs
  progName <- getProgName
  let header = "Usage: " ++ progName ++ " [OPTION...]"
  let helpMessage = usageInfo header options
  case getOpt RequireOrder options argv of
    (opts, [], []) ->
      case foldM (flip id) defaultOptions opts of
        Right opts -> return opts
        Left errorMessage -> ioError (userError (errorMessage ++ "\n" ++ helpMessage))
    (_, _, errs) -> ioError (userError (concat errs ++ helpMessage))

main :: IO ()
main = do
  options <- parseArgs
  putStrLn $ show options
```

How can I improve this?