# Creating a simple cli argument parser via pattern matching

Tags: haskell

I am working on a little project in Haskell and currently I am trying to make it more extensible by adding the possibility of using optional cli flags.

The desired interface would look as this:

```
program: [--command1 {n} ] [--help]
```

with `command1` and `help` being optional arguments, and furthermore, `command1` can also take an integer argument `n`.

Using patterm matching, I came up with the following result

```hs
main :: IO ()
main = do
        args <- getArgs
        case args of
          []                -> command1'
          ["--command1", a] -> if isJust (readMaybe n::Maybe Int)
                             then command1 a-- handle proper integer
                             else -- call command1' but also show a warning message
          ["--command1"]   -> command1'
          ["--help"]      -> putStrLn showWarningMessage

          _ -> putStrLn (showErrorMessage args) -- show an error message
```

As the program does not rely on a certain parameter to be present, it should be able to run even if the cli arguments aren't valid.

I am unsure how to handle the following situations:

1. How to handle the case when a is not an integer and thus, we want to warn the user but also call `command1'`?
2. What to do in the situation when wrong arguments are added. The pattern match is exhaustive so arguments as `--command2` would be captured but what to do if args is of the form `args=[--command2, --command1, n]` or `args=[--command1, --command2]`. In both of this cases ideally an warning would be printed regarding `command2` being unknown but the cli should accept command1.

Note: I saw that there are libraries specifically designed to handle these issues but I am interested in solving these simple cases in order to learn Haskell better. Of course, there could be more edge cases but for my usage, the two mentioned are my only concern.

Comment: As a user of CLI programs, I would say your current solution is perfect. If I give you surprising or illegal arguments, don't just warn me and then do what you hope I meant. Print an error and tell me what's allowed.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback @amalloy, I will keep it in mind! The question I still feel (at least for me) provides a little interesting situation to handle in Haskell, even if I think in the end I will probably settle for the workflow you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert, but here are my answers:

**1.** What would be working for you is a simple `do` notation in your `else`, and provide a default value for the call to `command1`, since I assume your function needs an Integer to do something. Which would end up something like that :

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    case args of
        []                -> command1'
        ["--command1", a] -> if isJust (readMaybe n::Maybe Int)
                                then command1 a
                                -- here what I think you want to do
                                else do
                                    -- here your warning message
                                    putStrLn (showWarningMessage args)
                                    -- here let's say 10 is the default value 
                                    command1 10
        ["--command1"]    -> command1'
        ["--help"]        -> putStrLn showWarningMessage

        _ -> putStrLn (showErrorMessage args) -- show an error message
```

I found that in http://www.happylearnhaskelltutorial.com/1/times_table_train_of_terror.html#s18.4 which you can begin from start, it explains well the concepts of Haskell.

**2.** I understand what your are trying to do, but isn't the purpose of a commandline prompt to fail fast ? Keep in mind that you must focus on what are the default values, and doing so, what should be the default behaviour of your tool. And maybe you can think of a different implementation of your params. This is what I learned from few months of Haskell, coming myself from imperative languages.

Anyway I have some hints about how to do this. And what if you add a `command3` ? Your approach with describing all the possible use cases and manage everything by hand can lead easily to oversights and bugs. Without using an external library, this management can be avoided by using *System.Console.GetOpt*, the built-in parser of Haskell. Even if the [documentation](https://wiki.haskell.org/GetOpt) is a bit old they explain some concepts about flags and parsing.
I also found this post on Stack Overflow which shows a working example https://stackoverflow.com/a/10816382/6270743 with GetOpt. Based on that, I was not able to show an error message AND execute the command which is what you try to do.

But the code, even not perfect, handles perfectly every combination of flags/params and catches all the errors with 4 different params. Here it is with some comments :

```
import Control.Monad (foldM)
import System.Console.GetOpt
import System.Environment ( getArgs, getProgName )

data Options = Options {
      optVerbose        :: Bool
    , optShowVersion    :: Bool
    , optNbOfIterations :: Int
    , optSomeString     :: String
    } deriving Show

defaultOptions = Options {
      optVerbose         = False
    , optShowVersion     = False
    , optNbOfIterations  = 1
    , optSomeString      = "a random string"
    }

options :: [OptDescr (Options -> Either String Options)]
options =
    [ Option ['v']     ["verbose"]
        (NoArg (\ opts -> Right opts { optVerbose = True }))
        "chatty output on stderr"

    , Option ['V','?'] ["version"]
        (NoArg (\ opts -> Right opts { optShowVersion = True }))  -- here no need for a value for this option because of `NoArg`
        "show version number"

    , Option ['i'] ["iterations"] 
        (ReqArg (\ i opts -> -- here the value of the param is required `ReqArg`, but you can also have `OptArg` which makes the value optional
            case reads i of
                [(iterations, "")] | iterations >= 1 && iterations <= 20 -> Right opts { optNbOfIterations = iterations } -- here your conditions
                _ -> Left "--iterations must be a number between 1 and 20" -- error message in case previous conditions are not met
        ) "ITERATIONS")  -- here the name of the param in the cli help
        "Number of times you want to repeat the reversed string" -- here the description of param's usage in the cli help

    , Option ['s'] ["string"]
        (ReqArg (\arg opts ->  Right opts { optSomeString = return arg !! 0 } -- really dirty, sorry but could not make it work another way
        "Outputs the string reversed"
    ]

parseArgs :: IO Options
parseArgs = do
  argv <- getArgs
  progName <- getProgName
  let header = "Usage: " ++ progName ++ " [OPTION...]"
  let helpMessage = usageInfo header options
  case getOpt RequireOrder options argv of
    (opts, [], []) ->
      case foldM (flip id) defaultOptions opts of
        Right opts -> return opts
        Left errorMessage -> ioError (userError (errorMessage ++ "\n" ++ helpMessage))
    (_, _, errs) -> ioError (userError (concat errs ++ helpMessage))


main :: IO ()
main = do
  options <- parseArgs
  if isVerbose options
  then mapM_ putStrLn ["verbose mode activated !","You will have a lot of logs","With a lot of messages","And so on ..."]
  else return () -- do nothing
  mapM_ print (repeatReversedString options)
  if getVersion options
  then print "version : 0.1.0-prealpha"
  else return ()
  return ()


-- With those functions we extract the option setting from the data type Options (and maybe we play with it)
isVerbose :: Options -> Bool
isVerbose (Options optVerbose _ _ _) = optVerbose

getVersion :: Options -> Bool
getVersion (Options _ optShowVersion _ _) = optShowVersion

repeatReversedString :: Options -> [String]
repeatReversedString (Options _ _ optNbOfIterations optSomeString) =
    replicate optNbOfIterations (reverse optSomeString)

getString :: Options -> String
getString (Options _ _ _ optSomeString) = optSomeString
```

I think you can achieve your goal by using OptArg (instead ofthe  NoArg and ReqArg I used), which has this definition :
`OptArg (Maybe String -> a) String`

Here is the link on hackage :
https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/System-Console-GetOpt.html

Remember that Haskell is very different from other common languages as for example you have no for loops !